# Take previous row's value in dataframe when condition meets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datafarme let's say something like this:

```
| ColumnX        |
| -------------- |
| Hi             |
| + Open         |
| How are you    |
| NAN            |
| Something      |
| something      |
| HEY            |
| + Open         |
```

now I need to go through the rows checking their values.  If the row value is "+ Open" then select the **previous** row value and put it into a list.
so far this is what I've done but I couldn't figure out how to take the previous value-

```
ilist=[]
for i in df["ColumnX"]:
    if i == '+ Open':
        ilist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the mask for values, shift the mask passing -1, then fill NA by False which is basically the last row, then use this mask to get the values and finally create list out of the values:

```py
>>> df.loc[df['ColumnX'].eq('+ Open').shift(-1).fillna(False) ,'ColumnX'].to_list()

# Output:
['Hi', 'HEY']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
ilist=[]
for i in range(0,len(df["ColumnX"])):
    if df["ColumnX"][i] == '+ Open':
        ilist.append(df["ColumnX"][i-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate` and acces the previous value by index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["Hi", "+ Open", "How are you", "NAN", "Something", "Something", "HEY","+ Open"], columns=["ColumnX"])

ilist = []

for i, value in enumerate(df["ColumnX"]):
    if value == "+ Open" and i>0: # check if i>0 to prevent out of index error
        ilist.append(df.at[i-1, "ColumnX"])
        
print(ilist)
```

Out:

```
['Hi', 'HEY']
```